# Is this evergreen with yellow branches sick?

Tags: trees, evergreens

There is an evergreen in front of my apartment. In just a few days, many of its branches have turned yellow. Last week it still looked fine. Is this expected, or is the tree sick? Is there anything I can do to help it?

I have no experience with trees at all. This tree is not technically my responsibility as it belongs to the apartment block. But I am quite worried about it and I would like to do everything I can to prevent it from dying.

[image]

Comment: It looks like some variety of spruce to me. Individual needles drop after 2 or 3 years anyway, but the patches of brown at the ends of the branches look like they are caused by a fungus infection or some other disease. Quite likely, the infected branches will die and drop off - but the tree as a whole might survive for many years. Unfortunately, there is no known cure for some of these problems, except pruning the infected branches.

Comment: Too wet or too hot/dry will also make a pine look like this. Sometimes it takes 3 or 4 years for drought damage to show up. There is no cure.